# Would this shorthand work within a function for the return?

Tags: php, function, return, ternary-operator

Would the below work? I'm not able to test it, and I was wondering (as I use very little shorthand coding techniques) if you're able to use shorthand for the return within a function? I can't think of any reason why it would not work, but I couldn't find anything online to verify.

```
function isOnline($ip, $port, $timeout = 1) {
    return (($fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $i, $j, $timeout)) ? fclose($fp) : false);
}
```

The `fclose()` function should return true, so the primary return is also true, correct?

Of course I can accomplish this easily the proper way, but I like learning new ways to do things.

Comment: Just tried it with google, works fine. `var_dump(isOnline("74.125.225.142",80));`

Comment: What do you mean you cannot test it? http://codepad.viper-7.com/mSXYLI and http://codepad.org/Yzh2tzTW

Comment: Gordon - was unaware of that resource, thank you for linking it. I'll be sure to utilize it in the future. Thanks David Chen and Gordon, both. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Using the ternary operator for something else than assignments – valid use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876307/php-using-the-ternary-operator-for-something-else-than-assignments-valid-use)