# PHP: Using the ternary operator for something else than assignments – valid use case?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Unfortunately I haven't found any official resource on this.

Is it allowed to use the ternary operator like this, to shorten and if/else statement:

```
(isset($someVar) ? $this->setMyVar('something') : $this->setMyVar('something else'));
```

In the PHP documentation, the ternary operator is explained with this example:

```
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'standard' : $_POST['action'];
```

This makes me believe that my use case might work, but it not really valid because a setter function does not return anything.

Comment: Sure can you use it that way. What is the problem? (As you say it: the ternary operator is a short if/else statement so you can use it the exact same way) I think it's more a question of readability.

Comment: i've used this before too, think it's ok to use if you don't care what's returning.

Comment: `?:` is an operator. An operator is used to connect (one or two or three) expressions into a bigger expression. It is not a replacement for the `if/then/else` statements. The two language constructs (the ternary operator and the `if/then/else` statements) are not mutually exclusive; there are pieces of code that can be written both ways.

Comment: In your case, I'd use the ternary like this: `$this->setMyVar(isset($someVar) ? 'something' : 'something else');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** From the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> [...] the ternary operator is an expression, and [...] it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression.

That quoted, although the ternary is mostly used for assigning values, you can use it as you suggested because a function call is an expression so the appropriate function will be evaluated (and therefore executed).

If your setter function would return a value, it would simply not be assigned to anything and would therefore be lost. However, since you said your setter doesn't return anything, the whole ternary operator will evaluate to nothing and return nothing. That's fine.

If this is more readable than a regular if/else is a different story. When working in a team, I would suggest to rather stick to a regular if/else.

Or, how about going with this syntax, which would be more common?

```
$this->myVar = isset($someVar) ? 'something' : 'something else';
```

Or, using your setter:

```
$this->setMyVar(isset($someVar) ? 'something' : 'something else');
```

Comment: Thank you – I was looking at the localized version of that article in my language and there this part is simply missing.